# Erroneous question in university course module

Tags: fractions, volume

A friend of mine is working on a course for a teaching position. She asked for help with a course question and we both had a bit of trouble with the language so she emailed the course provider. The response she got was even more confusing. In the response below, they subtract 2/3 from the number of jugs of icing they made. However this 2/3 refers to the total volume of icing, so they seem to be subtracting items of a different unit right? Like if we say T is the total volume and J is jugs 17/12J = 3/3T. By subtracting 17/12 - 2/3 they aren't subtracting 2/3 of the total but in fact 2/3 of a jug not the total. Am I right in this assessment?

[image: response from course provider]

Comment: That's a maths question at a *university*?

Comment: Haha I know right? It's just basic maths aptitude for a teaching course

Comment: You're right that the response, subtracting 2/3, is nonsense. You're also right that the question is unclear. It probably meant that, after making 17/12 cups (or whatever that pictorial unit is supposed to be), they used 2/3 of that amount (putting it on cakes) and you're supposed to figure out how much of the 17/12 remains unused. But it could mean that they had some supply of icing originally, they used up 17/12 cups of it, and you're supposed to figure out how much of the original supply was not used. That would produce the 17/24 answer that I see in your picture.

Comment: I assume what is meant is that they *made* 17/12 cups, used 2/3 of it, and now have 1/3 of 17/12 cups remaining, which would be 17/36 cups.

Comment: @AndreasBlass yeah the answer given there was my initial assumption that they made 2/3 of their supply of icing but i thinks its more likely that they used 2/3 of the icing they made upon reflection like you suggested giving an answer of 17/36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please reach back to the Web site to say that *there is a missing picture of a cup after the fraction $\frac{2}{3}$*. The question and their answer make sense if the real question is:

- Rachel made $\frac{5}{6}$ cups of icing
- Milan made $\frac{7}{12}$ cups of icing
- They then used $\frac{2}{3}$ **cups** of (total) icing

This is the only way I can explain their expected answer $\frac{5}{6}+\frac{7}{12}-\frac{2}{3}=\frac{3}{4}$.

Answer (score 0):

The question and answer are correct in the picture. It's about fraction addition and subtraction. They make the icing, combine their icing together, use some of it up and you have to find how much of the original icing they made is still left. The wording could be better though not gonna lie.

I see this as: the two people make icing, dump it all together  in a big container, then they take out 2/3 of it from that big container and then you find how find how much is left in that big container. Hope this helps.